# VS 2015 - Assign shortcut key to Add -> JavaScript File

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I would like to assign a keyboard shortcut for adding a new JavaScript file to a folder in my project. Under Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard I have added a shortcut to **ProjectandSolutionContextMenus.Project.Add.NewJavaScriptFile**, but it has no effect. Is it just not possible to assign shortcut keys to context menu items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried what you had done, and you're right -- the shortcut key doesn't work for some reason.  It's probably best to try an extension like 'Add New File' by Mads Kristensen.  You can download it at the link below or through the Extensions and Updates in visual studio.  Then you just use the hotkey shift + F2 and you can type in your file name and the extension, and your file is created.  Much easier than going through all the context menus.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3f820e99-6c0d-41db-aa74-a18d9623b1f3

Comment: Yep, I've been using that extension for quite a while now. We're 100% TypeScript now and Add New File is the easiest way to quickly create new .ts files.

Comment: Awesome.  It's such a nice extension.  My wrist was starting to hurt with right clicking and then navigating to the item.